# onMouseDrag with view and with tools

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I want to drag my whole view, but there is something wrong with what i'm doing :

```
    paper.view.onMouseDrag = function drag(event)
{
  alert("ee");
}
```

It's doesn't work, the propertie onMouseDrag contain the function drag, but this console.log never show up. And then when i do a things like this it work :

```
self.deplacerFond = new paper.Tool();
self.deplacerFond.onMouseDrag = dragDeplacerFond;
function dragDeplacerFond(event) {
console.log("test");
```

}

```
self.eventsSouris.deplacerFond.activate();
```

I tried this aslo :

```
var test = function(event) {
alert("test");


};

  view.on('mousedrag', test);
```

I'm a bit confuse, do i have to active the 'paper.view.onMouseDrag' too ?

(sorry for my poor english)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
paper.view.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
  alert("mousedown");
});
```

for mouse move

```
paper.view.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
      alert("move");
    });
```